# How to solve problem of my URL being changed

Tags: html, url

I am using session storage in my UI app. getting as `JSON` format all is good but the only issue is when I JSON value passing through in to URL. it is adding %22 value%22. So I want to remove %22 in the URL.
What is the solution for this.
Here is Snippet for the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a issu from angular, brower sometimes encode your URL,

```
encodeURI( "http://www.example.com/bar?foo=foo bar jar" ) 
Will generate: http://www.example.com/bar?foo=foo%20bar%20jar
```

so you just need decode your URL. like:

```
decodeURI( "http://www.example.com/bar?foo=foo%20bar%20jar" )
Will generate: http://www.example.com/bar?foo=foo bar jar
```